# Using the properties of real numbers, verify commutativity on complex numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have just started self-studying Linear Algebra after a 3 year hiatus from mathematics (in an extended neuroscience foray), and I want to ensure that I am sufficiently verifying commutativity of complex numbers by using the properties of real numbers.

My attempts...

(1) Commutativity of Addition:

Verify that $w + z = z + w$ for all $w, z \in \mathbb{C}$.

$$w + z = (a + bi) + (c + di) \hspace{10mm}\text{by definition of }\mathbb{C}$$
$$\hspace{13mm} = a + (bi + c) + di \hspace{10mm}\text{by associativity in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{17mm} = a + (c + bi) + di \hspace{10mm}\text{by commutativity in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{16mm} = (a + c) + (bi + di) \hspace{10mm}\text{by associativity in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{19mm} = (c + a) + (di + bi) \hspace{10mm}\text{by commutativity in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{13mm} = c + (a + di) + bi \hspace{10mm}\text{by associativity in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{17mm} = c + (di + a) + bi \hspace{10mm}\text{by commutativity in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{17mm} = (c + di) + (a + bi) \hspace{11mm}\text{by associativity in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{13mm} = z + w \hspace{34mm}\text{by definition of }\mathbb{C}$$

$$\blacksquare$$

This seems a bit verbose to me - is it acceptable to combine steps? For example, rather than: 
$$w + z = (a + bi) + (c + di) \hspace{10mm}\text{by definition of }\mathbb{C}$$
$$\hspace{13mm} = a + (bi + c) + di \hspace{10mm}\text{by associativity in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{17mm} = a + (c + bi) + di \hspace{10mm}\text{by commutativity in }\mathbb{R}$$
can I instead write:
$$w + z = (a + bi) + (c + di) \hspace{10mm}\text{by definition of }\mathbb{C}$$
$$\hspace{48mm} = a + (c + bi) + di \hspace{10mm}\text{by associativity and commutativity in }\mathbb{R}$$?

(2) Commutativity of Multiplication:

Verify that $wz = zw$ for all $w, z \in \mathbb{C}$.

$$\hspace{-14mm}wz = (a + bi)(c + di) \hspace{24mm}\text{by definition of }\mathbb{C}$$
$$\hspace{4mm} = a \cdot c + a \cdot di + bi \cdot c + bi \cdot di \hspace{10mm}\text{by distribution in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{9mm} = a \cdot c + bi \cdot c + a \cdot di + bi \cdot di \hspace{10mm}\text{by commutativity in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{35mm} = c \cdot a + c \cdot bi + di \cdot a + di \cdot bi \hspace{10mm}\text{by multiplicative commutativity in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{1mm} = c(a + bi) + di(a + bi) \hspace{20mm}\text{by distribution in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{5mm} = (c + di)(a + bi)\hspace{34mm}\text{by distribution in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\hspace{4mm} = zw \hspace{55mm}\text{by distribution in }\mathbb{R}$$
$$\blacksquare$$

This also seems a bit wonky to me. Any and all suggestions on clearing up my verification, reasoning, etc. would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you go from line 1 to line 2, I don't see why you are using associativity of Reals, when the numbers you are adding are not Real numbers. I would say associativity of the Complex numbers $a, ib, c, id$. But maybe your book's layout is different.

Comment: I think that it would be very good to use the definition of a complex number as an ordered tuple, i.e., if $z=x+iy$ then $z\equiv (x,y)$. Then you can apply the properties of $\mathbb{R}$ in respective components.

Answer (score 3):

the associativity and commutivity operations a little confused, you have to apply them to reals not the imaginary.

I think you should go to the definition of complex addition:

(w+z) = ( w_re + i*w_im ) + ( z_re + i*z_im) = (w_re+z_re) + i*(w_im + z_im)
then you can apply the commutativity on Reals to rearrange the order of the sums and show the commutativity.

Comment: Ok, this seems to have helped. I have reworked it as follows:

w + z = (a + bi) + (c + di) = (a + c) + (b + d)i = (c + a) + (d + b)i = (c + di) + (a + bi) = z + w.  QED.

First step is applying definition of complex number. Second step uses definition of complex addition. Third step uses commutativity of reals. Fourth uses definition of complex addition. Last step uses definition of complex number.

Does this seem correct?

Comment: For the second part, I have reworked it using complex multiplication.

wz = (a + bi)(c + di) = (ac - bd) + (ad + bc)i = (ca - db) + (da + cb)i = (ca - db) + (cb + da)i = (c + di)(a +bi) = zw. QED.

First step by definition of complex number. Second step definition of complex multiplication. Third step by commutativity of multiplication. Fourth step by commutativity of addition. Fifth step by definition of complex multiplication. Last step by definition of complex number.

Is this an appropriate result?